# Is there any software that allows live multiple webcam picture-in-picture via Skype or Google Hangout?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, webcam

I've looked in all the AskUbuntu forums, Stack Exchange forums, generic Google searches worded 23 different ways, YouTube searches worded 13 different ways, and still cannot find any answer to my problem; just know that I'm not coming here to ask this question cold and without prior research.

While I know that there are software packages suitable for multiple-webcam, picture-in-picture video recording and uploading to YouTube, what I'm wondering is this:

Has anyone ever heard of a software package that allows one to make real-time, live, picture-in-picture video calls using either Google Hangout or Skype (or similar webcam communication package)?

I teach music lessons using Google Hangout or Skype, depending upon my student's software and capabilities.  I need to have one camera videoing my head and upper torso, and, at the same time, have a second camera videoing my hands up close as I video-chat in real time.

Is there such a software package out there that would allow this?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04; I'm happy to give you all of my hardware specs if it turns out that there exists such a program and you need that info. (I may as well mention here that I'm a Linux n00b; copy-and-paste-able terminal commands would be sooo very much appreciated.)

Thanks in advance for your time; out of all the things you could have done, you looked at my little fussiness, so I thank you.

-Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What I use as a workaround for live training is to share the screen on one of those programs and show [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/), where I have set up the cameras and windows the way I want (2 webcams, the skype window, and the training software).

I've created a specific "Training" scene with those sources.

Answer (score 0):

**WebcamStudio** helps you create a virtual webcam that can show: Your desktop with your webcam in overlay - Your desktop/webcam with several video effects - You in all your glory! Compatible with Flash sites!

Last daily builds (12.04 not available):

https://launchpad.net/~webcamstudio/+archive/webcamstudio-dailybuilds

Check also:

http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/12.04/?q=webcamstudio

[image: WebcamStudio]

Comment: Abandoned since 2017 :(