# Can a webcam be used by more than one applications at the same time?

Tags: skype, webcam

Can a webcam be used by more than one applications at the same time? I would like to use it simultaneously under Skype and under guvcview, but it can't do that. Thanks!

Comment: Skype somehow "steals" the camera from being used by other things. maybe you can with Cheese and guvcview, but for sure not with Skype ;)

Comment: See also [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/416380/how-to-create-a-duplicate-of-dev-video0) & [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/412533/is-there-any-software-that-allows-live-multiple-webcam-picture-in-picture-via-sk)...